# How to rewrite iterator-based for loop into range-based (C++11)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, c++11, iterator

I would like to rewrite this for loop (which works)

```
for (vector<shared_ptr<Node<int>>>::iterator it = n.root.children.begin();
    it != n.root.children.end(); 
    ++it) 
    {cout << (*it)->value<<flush;}
```

into a range-based for loop. What I tried is

```
for (shared_ptr<Node<int>> child:(n.root).children){
       cout<<(child->value)<<" "<<flush;
    }
```

but it gives me a core dump. The root is of type Node

```
template <typename T>
class Node{
public:
    T value;
    vector<shared_ptr<Node>> children;
};
```

These lines in main.cpp work fine.

```
cout<<(n.root).value<<flush;
cout<<n.root.children.front()->value<<flush;
```

I use g++ 4.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go. Try this.

```
for (auto v : n.root.children ) {
    cout << v->value << flush;
}
```

Comment: This looks really nice. Unfortunately the result is the same as above - coredump.The coredump happens AFTER the values have been printed however. Like as if the compiler did not know when to end loop.

Comment: The answer is a direct translation of what we were given. The question now becomes, what is wrong that causes a crash? Post a stripped-down but compilable version, and we can solve it.

Comment: `const auto& v` would be better to avoid unnecessary copying of the container value type. For `std::shared_ptr` this is likely to be an interlocked increment and decrement.

Comment: Just noticed the executable behaves differently when building in Qt Creator and when running g++. I will research this and return when I know more.

Comment: @Bleep - There is probably no reason to be using shared_ptr at all. Two problems at a time, please. :-)

Comment: @Jive: He's already using a vector of shared pointers, I'm not telling him to start using them. The point would still be valid if it was a `std::vector<std::string>` - if you use auto v then you create a copy of the container element on each iteration.

Comment: There is something very wrong with the rest of my code. I will use the answer though, so closing the question. Thank you all.